# how to select rows on cellclick, and also columns on column header click?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, selection

Hello I want to select the column via columnheader click, and also select the row via cell click.

This code doesnt do the job.

```
 Private Sub datagridview2_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As              DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

    datagridview2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = True

End Sub
```

these gridview options I made in the code

```
    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In datagridview2.Columns
        c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable

        c.Selected = False
    Next

    datagridview2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

I hope someone can help out. Cheers b101

Edit: well column and row select works fia header click. Now it is needed to select one single cell by cell click.
The following code works, but with 2 clicks. the first click unselects row or column and the second click selects the single cell

```
Private Sub datagridview2_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.CellMouseClick
    datagridview2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect

End Sub
```

If I try to select the sell in the cell click event via e.columnindex e.rowindex
it throws a outofrangeexception. the indexes are totally stupid like -1 or some simililar index wich doesnt exist.

Edit 2:
This code doesnt work

```
Private Sub datagridview2_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.CellMouseClick


    datagridview2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
    datagridview2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = True




End Sub



Private Sub datagridview2_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

    datagridview2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect
    datagridview2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = True

End Sub

Private Sub datagridview2_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.RowHeaderMouseClick
    datagridview2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    datagridview2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
End Sub
```

When click on headers itjumps into cellmouseclick event

Comment: Sorry satson was at table soccer with department :)) It works with one exception, i cannot select a single table cell by clicking it with mouse.

Comment: on rowheader Click I want fullrowselection, on columnheaderclick I want full column selection, on cellclick, I want cellselection.

Comment: Hello Satson thx for your effort. It works with the exception, that  I can only switch to cell selection after column selection.
When rowselection is true I cannot switch to cell selection, first I need to switch to column selection!

Comment: if you press column header then column selection work, row header select row selection work, if you select cell that a cell selection. Now What kind of changes you want?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to update this thread. It was only a typo in cellklickmethod() I wrote gridiew1 instead of gridview2. It works all fine. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect
    DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = True

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = -1 And DataGridView1.SelectionMode <> DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = False Then
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex > -1 And DataGridView1.SelectionMode <> DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect Then
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```